# Have I configured the correct current supply for my TFT LCD Backlight?

Tags: resistors, lcd, display, touchscreen, tft

I am currently working on a custom PCB which integrates a 3.5" TFT LCD. I am planning on driving the TFT backlight using a MIC4801 LED Driver and want to make sure I have configured the correct current supply.

Looking at the LCD datasheet (see below) the forward current of the LCD backlight is 120mA. Is this the current output which the MIC4801 should be configured for?

[image: LCD Datasheet]

In the datasheet of the MIC4801 you can set the maximum current output of the MIC4801 by determining an appropriate resitor value on the RSET pin. You can determine the appropiate resistor value using the following formula:

R(kΩ) = 4920 * D / I(LED mA)   Where D is Duty Cycle

Based on this I calculated my resistor to be:

4920 * 1 / 120 = 41kΩ

To achieve this I have connected a 47K and 330K resistor in parallel like so:

[image: PCB Schematic]

Is this correct? Are my resistor values okay? Am I using the correct current value to calculate the value of the resistors?

Comment: You could replace the circuit by a single series resistor 15 ohm / 0.5 W.

Comment: Would there not be issues due to voltage fluctuations between diodes and temperature changes if I were to just use a series resistor?

Comment: Yes, in a small amount. I would use 18 ohm to extend backlight life and to meet any thermal drifts of LED forwand voltage and supply voltage variations.